# Specifying an architecture in gdb-multiarch

Tags: c, gdb

If I compile a C program with any arm compiler (e.g. `arm-none-eabi-gcc`) and afterwards call `gdb-multiarch` with the binary as second paramter, it will correctly determine the machine type and I can debug my remote application.

If however I call `gdb-multiarch` on its own, it will assume my machine type (x86_64) and tries to debug the remote target with the wrong architecture..

How do I specify the machine type/architecture (e.g. `armv5te`) in `gdb-multiarch`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The fine manual says](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Targets.html#Targets):

> `set architecture arch`
>
> This command sets the current target architecture to arch. The value of arch can be
> "`auto`", in addition to one of the supported architectures.

This sure sounds like what you're after, to me.