# gdb-multiarch (MINGW64) cannot determine architecture from executable?

Tags: debugging, gdb, cpu-architecture

I have seen in [Specifying an architecture in gdb-multiarch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684272/specifying-an-architecture-in-gdb-multiarch) :

> If I compile a C program with any arm compiler (e.g. arm-none-eabi-gcc) and afterwards call gdb-multiarch with the binary as second param(e)ter, it will correctly determine the machine type and I can debug my remote application.

I am using `mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb-multiarch 12.1-1` on MINGW64 (MSYS2) on Windows 10; and unfortunately, it seems it cannot determine the architecture. I have built an executable for Pico/RP2040 with `gcc` on this same system, and the system sees it as:

```
$ file myexecutable.elf
myexecutable.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped
```

However, if I try to run this in gdb-multiarch, I get:

```
$ gdb-multiarch myexecutable.elf
GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1
...

warning: A handler for the OS ABI "Windows" is not built into this configuration
of GDB.  Attempting to continue with the default armv6s-m settings.

Reading symbols from myexecutable.elf...
(gdb)
```

Well, as the warning says, it seems that `gdb-multiarch` sees this .elf as 'OS ABI "Windows"' - similar to what was noted in [Specifying an architecture in gdb-multiarch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55684272/specifying-an-architecture-in-gdb-multiarch) :

> If however I call gdb-multiarch on its own, it will assume my machine type (x86_64) and tries to debug the remote target with the wrong architecture..

... except, here I'm calling gdb-multiarch with the binary as second parameter - and I still have that problem!

The linked question already explains that `set architecture arch` from within GDB should work; however, I'm not exactly sure what to enter: `file` says this executable is "ARM, EABI5", and I've tried to derive an architecture label from that, which doesn't quite work:

```
(gdb) set architecture armeabi5
Undefined item: "armeabi5".
```

... and I'm not that knowledgeable with ARM, so that I'd know exactly what to enter here manually.

Therefore, I would prefer if `gdb-multiarch` found the architecture on its own automatically.

How can I persuade `gdb-multiarch` to detect the (ARM) architecture of the compiled file correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be trying to use a multiarch GDB suitable for use on Intel architectures only.
You can check by starting GDB and entering the following command:
`set architecture`. If this is the case, the list of supported architectures will look like this:

```
(gdb) set architecture
Requires an argument. Valid arguments are i386, i386:x86-64, i386:x64-32, i8086, i386:intel, i386:x86-64:intel, i386:x64-32:intel, auto.
(gdb)
```

For debugging a `cortex-m0` target, I would suggest using the GDB provided with the Arm [arm-none-eabi toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/11.2-2022.02/binrel/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi.zip), `arm-none-eabi-gdb`:

```
(gdb) set architecture
Requires an argument. Valid arguments are arm, armv2, armv2a, armv3, armv3m, armv4, armv4t, armv5, armv5t, armv5te, xscale, ep9312, iwmmxt, iwmmxt2, armv5tej, armv6, armv6kz, armv6t2, armv6k, armv7, armv6-m, armv6s-m, armv7e-m, armv8-a, armv8-r, armv8-m.base, armv8-m.main, armv8.1-m.main, arm_any, auto.
(gdb) 

(gdb) set architecture armv6-m
The target architecture is set to "armv6-m".
(gdb)
```

Architecture for `Cortex-M0`/`Cortex-M0+` is `armv6-m`, but I was always able to debug `Cortex-M0` programs with GDB without having to use `set architecture`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a ton - great reference on `set architecture`; turns out my `gdb-multiarch` reports support for some 360+ architectures, including `mips:*` and `arm*`. Also, thanks for noting `armv6-m` is for Cortex-M0/Cortex-M0+ - I was wondering why my gdb-multiarch chose `armv6s-m`, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/gcc/ARM-Options.html notes it is "the ‘armv6-m’ architecture with support for the (now mandatory) SVC instruction."

Comment: So, apparently, the confusion stems from the `warning: A handler for the OS ABI ...` message; https://www.physik.tu-cottbus.de/users/george/doc/gdb/gdbint_9.html#SEC68 (9. Target Architecture Definition / 9.1 Operating System ABI Variant Handling) notes that gdb tries to "sniff" the OS; `show osabi` command for me shows `The current OS ABI is "auto" (currently "Windows"). ; The default OS ABI is "Windows".` The commands `set osabi none` and/or `set architecture armv6s-m` suppress this warning, but it is still shown at startup.

Comment: To get rid of the warning even at `gdb-multiarch` startup, I had to do `mkdir ~/.config/gdb`, and then `echo "set osabi none" > ~/.config/gdb/gdbinit` ... And with that, I can finally run `gdb-multiarch myexecutable.elf` without getting that warning! (and if I issue `show architecture` here, I get "`The target architecture is set to "auto" (currently "armv6s-m").`", which means auto-detection is good)

Comment: `gdb-multiarch -iex "set osabi none" myexecutable.elf` should likely also work.